# How to use Xamarin Forms and Google Direction API android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

i m new to Xamarin Forms, While Creating an Android Application using Xamarin Forms, I encountered a problem, I like to use **Google Direction** API , I can create Map using Xamarin Forms on Android but to use **HTTPURLConnection** and **json** Parsing, *do i have to create **Custom Renderer** Class and then access in Android Dir and Code there, Or i can create a Class for  HTTPURLConnection, Json Parsing and then pass to Xamarin Forms map as class object*. Please Help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google direction APIs are not exposed in Xamarin.Forms because they are not available cross-platform. Baked into Forms is only the basic mapping support which abstracts away the differences between Google Maps, Apple Maps and Bing Maps.

For anything more specialised/more platform specific you will have to create a custom renderer and/or use some architectural design to connect your shared code and the platform code (you could use the `DependencyService` - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/).